# Android HTTP get methods

Tags: android

I have written a number of applications for blackberry and am just starting in Android.  It seems to me that android has a lot more built in functions.  I am starting by recreating some of my BB apps on Android and on one I take a few xml sites and parse them out.  On blackberry I implemented this by creating a class that extended a thread.  I would construct a new instance of this class with the parameters of my http request and it would call a function back in my main class, sending it the results.  I am tempted to reuse my code, but am curious if android has something better built in.  I have been looking at the handler class as well as possible using a service.

Bascially, I would like to start a new thread that will return a document of a specific url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You mean get a request?
Refer to this

http://hmkcode.com/android-internet-connection-using-http-get-httpclient/

And see 'Using AsyncTask' (unless you use the earlier API

For me, it work